# How to hide file and directory under /sys in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, sysfs

I am working on an embedded Linux system (with kernel 5.10.24).
I am trying to disable sysfs from kernel, but I found some other stuffs relies on sysfs, so I have to enable sysfs in kernel build.

Now I want to hide file and directory under `/sys`, or disable the listing `/sys/`.
I changed the `/etc/fstab` for mounting `/sys` as follows,
`sysfs           /sys            sysfs   ro,noexec       0       0`.

and `ls -l /` shows followings,
`dr-xr-xr-x   13 root     root             0 Jan  1  2020 sys`

I can still get list with `ls -l /sys`.

So is there a way to mount sysfs as write-only (cannot list stuffs under `/sys`)?

Comment: Hi! That sounds a bit strange. What is the purpose of disallowing listing of sysfs? I'm pretty sure a write-only sysfs won't be very useful, either

Comment: Marcus, I just want to ask how to make sysfs `write-only`, this is because, there are plenty of detailed info is exposed by sysfs, and for an embedded system, most of this info is redundent and not be used by application. So I would like to set sysfs as `write-only`.

Comment: That makes no sense – sysfs is part of your kernel API. Very little of that is redundant, and basically nothing related to system initialization would work without reading it. Which **problem** are you solving? Are you intending to sandbox some software? In that case, Linux namespaces (as used by *containers*) are probably the way to go.

Comment: This is an embedded system, currently no password protected. So anyone can grab the system information for reverse-engineering if he can get the console, it is not secured. So I want to make sysfs write-only. Alternatively, I found in this embedded system, USB gadget is used, which relies on sysfs, if using USB gadget without relying on sysfs, sysfs can be totally dis-configured from kernel.

Comment: If anybody can get access, then write-only mounting sysfs solves exactly nothing? I honestly fail to see the real problem this addresses, or how it is even remotely a solution?

Comment: For instance, the system is for a pre-production product, showing the chip or hardware info is NOT acceptable. It needs to omit some low level info from customer who is evaluating the product. For example, we can change the /proc/cpuinfo not to show real CPU model/arch. But /sysfs also exposes many detailed info which can not be published so far.

Comment: If that is not acceptable, then shipping a device with an unsecured console port is not acceptable. Sysfs is a userland requirement, you simply cannot sensibly do what you want, and doing what you want also solves none of the problems you describe – if I need to know which hardware is inside, I simply look at what the processor tells me, directly, no need for a detour through sysfs. Again, if I get access to an unsecured console that gives me access to your filesystem, your hardware confidentiality is gone, and sysfs really isn't the problem there.

Comment: The unsecured console to make it easy for customer to access the system. And as you said, you can access the processor info when you get into the console. But I would inhibit the user to access the `/proc/cpuinfo`, `/dev/kmsg` and other stuffs containing arch/model info. This is a design in-house SoC, not to publish it details at pre-production product. Now sysfs is the main part leaking hardware info, which needs to be delt with some tricks.

Comment: but you said this is an unrestricted shell, right, which means that any user can just mount these file systems as they want. Also, still not convinced you're actually hiding anything that way? like, what is an example of something that can *only* be figured out by looking at sysfs? And if that is all, why is not being able to list that file system any help (considering one could just brute-force pseudo-file names e.g. for bus enumeration)?

Comment: You know there are lots of files in sysfs exposing device tree, which show the chip and hardware details. So you are right, instead of changing sysfs, I can try adding root and regular users, set different restrictions to access filesystems. Or another solution might be making USB gadget work without using `CONFIGFS` (is it possible)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do you think your customer will want to buy a hardware platform that, for reasons they can't verify, is only supported by your rather strangely restricted Linux configuration? No. Embedded users want a mainline-as-possible kernel. Also, your whole idea of not telling the user the device tree means you **cannot legally use Linux**. The Linux kernel license is very clear: when you deliver a device containing a Linux kernel, you also have to make the source code of your kernel, **including all scripts necessary to build that kernel** available to the recipient.

Comment: So this is honestly all moot. You cannot stop your customer from suing you to give them your device tree and full modified kernel source. You cannot even bind them via NDA to not give out that code to third parties. **GPL v2** – it's not an optional license.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing out the license. Another off-topic question? If I encrypt the kernel image with SSL, shall I publish the keys doing the encryption? Bakc to the original topic, without changing the sysfs, but I can still disable it from kernel configuration. And I can change the some drivers to use `devfs` not `sysfs`, this should be legal, right? Now I am using USB gadget which relies on sysfs, so how to configure and use USB gadget without using `CONFIGFS` (on sysfs)?

Comment: configfs is the kernel API for that. I don't think you can without.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an option to make `sysfs` content write-only with regular Linux tools.

If it would be enough to limit the `sysfs` content for certain processes then I see two options:

## bind mounts

Create e.g. `/sys-limited` and `mount --bind ...` there everything those apps need from `/sys`. Then you put those processes into a separate mount namespace (can be the same for all) and in that you `mount --bind /sys-limited /sys`.

## FUSE

Much more work (OK, that depends on how much change you need to `/sys`) but more flexible: You write your own FUSE module which, of course, can offer write-only access, too, or just show the entries you have whitelisted. Then you mount it at `/sys-limited` and do the namespace separation mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to be frank, your answer is out of knowledge domain.  And I am not sure if the resource is enough to do that in an customized embedded system. I would study more on stuff you mentioned and validate your answer once I get prepared. I would up your answer, but I don't know so far if it is right/correct for my original ask.